# How to get the return of a sql server procedure on Pentaho?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, pentaho

I have a Pentaho transformation with three steps:

1. Table input. It works perfectly.
2. Execute SQL script, which I exec a sql server procedure. This procedure returns 4 tables, but I am not able to catch this three tables.
3. Text file output. Here I would like to save the contains of the before returned tables.

My main problem is that my partners have developed a procedure that returns some tables, when clearly this is a misunderstanding of the procedure concept. It should be a table valued function.

Despite this, I have to fix this someway, so, I am asking for advise. Anyone knows how to catch the tables?

Greetings.

Comment: Why would we assume that a procedure that returns a data set should be a TVF? Is there a hard rule that I am not aware of?

Comment: @JacobH thanks for your answer. Technically, and if I am not wrong a procedure is created to stablish change on data. For example, a procedure to change data type, or move data betweeb tables. A function is to read and manipulate data on fly to finally return some values, for example, when you need some field value for an specified id.

When I studied database objects this was the main difference between boths, in theory, but in hands on this is not always trues as this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this in the past and I believe it is not possible (although I can't seem to find the docs at the moment). Even if you could achieve this, how would you tell Pentaho what to do with each of the separate tables?

My solution at the time was to alter the proc so that only a single table was returned. Either by splitting the proc into several procs or combining the output into a single larger table with a parameter to split out in Pentaho.

Comment: Thanks @Raven-BlueDragon